# When I read "MPEG-4 AAC", does this mean 'AAC', 'AAC+ Version 1', or 'AAC+ Version 2'?

Tags: software, aac-m4a, 3gp

I'm encoding .3gp videos.

Instructions say, under audio codec: "MPEG-4 AAC".

On audio settings, I can choose between "AAC", "AAC+ Version 1" and "AAC+ Version 2".

I'm lost. Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: This question seems more broadcast and compression specific than AV Production! Inviting you to a new site proposal [Broadcast and Media Technologies](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/36807/broadcast-and-media-technologies) which aims to capture more architectural and theoretical views around subjects like this. Join and invite others.

Answer (score 2):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-Efficiency_Advanced_Audio_Coding):

The chart on the side states that **MPEG-4 AAC** is Low Complexity, which is the AAC option.

AAC+ V1 and V2 are the High Efficiency AAC versions of the codec.

Comment: You may want to check compatibility with what you are encoding for - I had problems in Premiere Pro with AAC until I encoded using the LC (Low Complexity) profile.